# How to Feed Real time data for Live chart in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have line chart Sample from D3..The Problem is I need to feed live data coming from server on time intervals and give it to D3 for drawing chart..As for as I have searched I am not able to find a single sample for that..Kindly please help me with this..I have tried some AJAX coding..Below is my code...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../D3/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script>



            var t = -1;
            var n = 40;
            var v = 0;
            var data = d3.range(n).map(next);

            function next() {
                return {
                    time: ++t,
                    value: v = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
                };
            }

            var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 },
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([0, n - 1])
                      .range([0, width]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([0, 20])
                      .range([height, 0]);

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                      .interpolate('basis')
                      .x(function (d, i) { console.log(d.time); return x(d.time); })
                      .y(function (d, i) { return y(d.value); });


            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


            var g = svg.append("g")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


            var graph = g.append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                          .scale(x)
                          .orient("bottom");

            var axis = graph.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                            .call(xAxis);

            g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

            var path = graph.append("g")
                          .append("path")
                          .data([data])
                          .attr("class", "line")
                          .attr("d", line);

            tick();

            function tick() {
                // push a new data point onto the back
                data.push(next());

                // update domain
                x.domain([t - n, t]);

                // redraw path, shift path left
                path
                    .attr("d", line)
                    .attr("transform", null)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .ease("linear")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + t - 1 + ")")
                    .each("end", tick);

                // shift axis left
                axis
                    .transition()
                    .duration(700)
                    .ease("linear")
                    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

                // pop the old data point off the front
                data.shift();
            }

            function loaddata() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "graph.txt ", true);
                xhttp.send();
            }





</script>
</head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="loaddata()">GET DATA</button>

        <div id="demo"></div>
        <style>
             body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
        line-height: 12pt;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #555555;
    }

    .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }

     </style>    
   </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to feed live data to `d3.js` using `socket.io`:
https://github.com/tyler-speakman/nodejs-d3js-with-socket-io-demo

Front-end:
https://github.com/tyler-speakman/nodejs-d3js-with-socket-io-demo/blob/master/index.html

Sever:
https://github.com/tyler-speakman/nodejs-d3js-with-socket-io-demo/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Wow!Thats What i was Searching for..Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem with this example is it seems he s not translating, if you run the code, you will notice how the change happens in an awkward manner